# How to inflate one view with a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I have a layout defined in XML. It contains also:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

I would like to inflate this RelativeView with other XML layout file. I may use different layouts depending on a situation. How should I do it? I was trying different variations of

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.item);
item.inflate(...)
```

But none of them worked fine.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

I'm not sure I have followed your question- are you trying to attach a child view to the RelativeLayout? If so you want to do something along the lines of:

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
item.addView(child);
```

Comment: I get an error: 02-25 22:21:19.324: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(865): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @MichalDymel: you probably are inflating same xml agian. should inflate another.

Comment: Just tried this now, I needed: View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child,null);

Comment: The problem isn't the code. It's fairly easy to follow code. Where do you make the xml file. is the type a theme style resource? the problem i think people me included is where are we placing this xml file

Comment: This isn't perfect. The 3-param version of the inflater should be used - here is why: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: Note: 3-param version does NOT have to be used for AlertDialog and PopupWindow.  You can supply 'null' as the ViewGroup parameter for these.

Comment: The answer is incorrect, even if it works. Please check out this post                    https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: @akshayrajkore your answer should be get more thumb ups, now i know why when i inflate a layout, the attributes being ignored, thanks bro

Comment: Current *Layout Inflation as Intended* link: https://wiresareobsolete.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Answer (score 112):

You inflate an XML resource. See the [LayoutInflater doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) .

If your layout is in a *mylayout.xml*, you would do something like:

```
View view; 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
```

Comment: I have my main view inflated. The problem is I want to inflate part of it from other XML file. This item RelativeLayout is part of bigger layout and I want to fill it with layout from another XML file.

Comment: hum I m sorry then I have no clue :( . Are you using something like <include> in your main view to include other layout?

Comment: No, it's simple layout. I think I will just add my elements programatically - without XML. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 28):

Though late answer, 
but would like to add that one way to get this

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, item );
```

where `item` is the parent layout where you want to add a child layout.

Comment: (even later still) I am having difficulty implementing your answer. I tried the code you mentioned above but replaced 'item' with: 'R.layout.activity_layout'

I'm getting an "There is no applicable method to '(int,int)'" could I trouble you for your thoughts?

Comment: @Kyle - even later still. You cant use `R` resources as references to an object, they are just `int`s. You have to use `findViewById` passing it the `R` resource, then type cast it to your desired object. Then you can use it in function calls like `inflate`. (ie. `ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.activity_layout);`... then you can use `item` like above.)

Comment: I guess I ment to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `ViewGroup` there in my example above, as you cant instantiate the base class `ViewGroup`. 5 minute edit rule got me. lol

Comment: Is it possible to hide parent and display only child view

Comment: Thanks, this method helped out where I couldn't use the getContext() in the previous example since I am using fragments.

Comment: Glad it helped someone :-)

Comment: @ShaistaNaaz Hi..I have created multiple view of same type..by inflate them ..i got a problem how am i supposed to get the each item resource id.

Comment: I inflated some view (`ImageView`) and set it as action view - `menuItem.setActionView(view);` - `menuItem` is parent here?

Answer (score 20):

It's helpful to add to this, even though it's an old post, that if the child view that is being inflated from xml is to be added to a viewgroup layout, you need to call inflate with a clue of what type of viewgroup it is going to be added to. Like:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, item, false);
```

The inflate method is quite overloaded and describes this part of the usage in the docs. I had a problem where a single view inflated from xml wasn't aligning in the parent properly until I made this type of change.

Comment: Finally, thank you :) This allows to add multiple views to a single parent, but without the need to worry about the LayoutParams - which are read from the XML. Good job!

Answer (score 14):

Even simpler way is to use

```
View child = View.inflate(context, R.layout.child, null)
item.addChild(child) //attach to your item
```

Comment: Using `View.inflate()`is the best way, no unnecessary `LayoutInflater` or `getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` or any of all that nuisance!  :D

Answer (score 11):

Try this code :

1. If you just want to inflate your layout :

```html
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout,null); // Code for inflating xml layout
RelativeLayout item = view.findViewById(R.id.item);
```

2. If you want to inflate your layout in container(parent layout) :

```html
LinearLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.container);        //parent layout.
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout,parent,false); 
RelativeLayout item = view.findViewById(R.id.item);       //initialize layout & By this you can also perform any event.
parent.addView(view);             //adding your inflated layout in parent layout.
```

Answer (score 9):

layout inflation

```
View view = null;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
main.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're not in an activity you can use the static `from()` method from the `LayoutInflater` class to get a `LayoutInflater`, or request the service from the context method `getSystemService()` too :

```
LayoutInflater i;
Context x;       //Assuming here that x is a valid context, not null

i = (LayoutInflater) x.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//OR
i = LayoutInflater.from(x);
```

(I know it's almost 4 years ago but still worth mentioning)

Answer (score 6):

**AttachToRoot Set to True**

Just think we specified a button in an XML layout file with its layout width and layout height set to match_parent.

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/custom_button">
</Button>
```

On This Buttons Click Event We Can Set Following Code to Inflate Layout on This Activity.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutname, this);
```

Hope this solution works for you.!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a single view multiple time then you have to use

```
   layoutInflaterForButton = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

 for (int noOfButton = 0; noOfButton < 5; noOfButton++) {
        FrameLayout btnView = (FrameLayout) layoutInflaterForButton.inflate(R.layout.poll_button, null);
        btnContainer.addView(btnView);
    }
```

If you do like

```
   layoutInflaterForButton = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    FrameLayout btnView = (FrameLayout) layoutInflaterForButton.inflate(R.layout.poll_button, null);
```

and

```
for (int noOfButton = 0; noOfButton < 5; noOfButton++) {
            btnContainer.addView(btnView);
        }
```

then it will throw exception of all ready added view.

Answer (score 3):

If you are you trying to attach a child view to the RelativeLayout? you can do by following

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, item, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the hardest time with this error, because of my unique circumstances, but finally found a solution.

My situation: I am using a separate view (XML) which holds a `WebView`, then opens in an `AlertDialog` when I click a button in my main activity view. But somehow or another the `WebView` belonged to the main activity view (probably because I pull the resource from here), so right before I assigned it to my `AlertDialog` (as a view), I had to get the parent of my `WebView`, put it into a `ViewGroup`, then remove all the views on that `ViewGroup`. This worked, and my error went away.

```
// set up Alert Dialog box
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// inflate other xml where WebView is
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_webview_layout, null);
final WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_webview_id);

// more code...
```

.... later on after I loaded my `WebView` ....

```
// first, remove the parent of WebView from it's old parent so can be assigned a new one.
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) webView.getParent();
vg.removeAllViews();

// put WebView in Dialog box
alert.setView(webView);
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

With Kotlin, you can use:

```
val content = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.[custom_layout_name], null)

[your_main_layout].apply {
    //..
    addView(content)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When add a layout to an Activity in Kotlin, see these steps:

1. Add just in Activity - One layout as a parent
2. Xml file of new
3. Layout  Give the value of R.

   val parent: LinearLayout =findViewById(R.id.stars)

   ```
   val view =
       LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(R.layout.another, parent,false)
   ```

Where `parent` is not necessary, can be `null` But warning message will be appear

```
view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivTimer).setImageResource(R.drawable.t2)
```

Any view must be **set value** in this way, finally `add`

```
parent.apply {  addView(view)}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had used below snippet of code for this and it worked for me.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
linearLayout.addView(child);
```