# The best way to inflate view programmatically

Tags: android

I found a simple SwipeSample that I changed to allow me to create new xml layouts and inflate the main layout to display them. What I wanted to do was also be able to programmatically add layouts for the swipe process.

I have the main.xml layout and a red.xml and yellow.xml which are a simple linearlayout with a textview set to a solid color.

The code below works but I don't think that it's correct or the best way to do what I'm trying to get. 
If anyone can suggest a better way that would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Create a layout with a solid blue background programmatically
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("Blue");
    tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ll.addView(tv1);
    //Create a layout with a solid green background programmatically
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText("Green");
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ll2.addView(tv2);
    //inflate the flipper view and add the yellow and red xml layouts and also the 2 programmatically created layouts
    fSpace = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.yellow, fSpace);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.red, fSpace);
    fSpace.addView(ll);
    fSpace.addView(ll2);  

}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have a complex layout that you want to create programmatically, it might be easiest to have the layout premade in xml and then just inflate it and add it at runtime.

## Create view in xml

Here is a sample premade xml layout that is in the layout folder. Yours could be anything, a single view or a whole complex layout.

layout/my_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:text="This is a TV"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:text="How are you today?"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

## Make a container for your view

Have some place it put your view in your activity layout. You could have something like this.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</FrameLayout>
```

## Inflate the view

Use get a reference to the container, inflate your view from xml, and then add it to the container.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
    View inflatedLayout= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, null, false);
    container.addView(inflatedLayout);

}
```

Doing it like this keeps your code a lot cleaner.

## See also:

- [How to inflate one view with a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-an-layout)
- [Add a View to a wrapper multiple times with inflate](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/14/add-a-view-to-a-wrapper-multiple-times-with-inflate/)

Answer (score 3):

The way you inflate R.layout.yellow and R.layout.red is indeed the right way to do so. You may be able to simplify your code by moving a lot of it over to xml. I assume tv1 is just a sample? if not, it could go into main.xml. You may even find a way to create yellow and red with a single inflation... depending on what you're doing.

Programmatically creating views is just, for the most part, slightly tedious.