# How to create custom view from xml-layout?

Tags: java, android

I have the xml layout, and I want to create View from it - I need do it programatically. Is it possible?

Comment: Here you [go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-an-layout/2335867#2335867)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes It is. you have to use the inflater service like

```
        LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        yourview=li.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I set width and height for my new view?

Comment: with layoutparams. take a look to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

put your xml in layout folder with some name say x.

Use getViewInflate().inflate(R.layout.x, null, null) to create the view.