# How to inflate a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tabs as activities. In one of the tabs I have a search dialog. When I inflate the search result my tabs disappear. How can I inflate the result while preserving the tabs?

Here's how I inflate the result:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.quick_search);

if(data==null) {

    LinearLayout empty = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.empty, null);

    layout.addView(empty);

}
else {

    LinearLayout workRequest = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.quick_search, null);

    layout.addView(workRequest);
}
```

Actually I want to display the searched result in place of `LinearLayout` 'quick_search' and make sure that the view above 'quick_search' is not lost. My current method inflates the result to occupy the whole screen. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

See the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336047/1441666

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child);
item.addView(child);
```

Comment: I tried this. The only difference between your answer and my code is you've specified child as a view instead of a Layout right? It doesn't work. I mean the view is inflated but it occupies the whole screen and I lose my tabs at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If `quick_search` or `empty` have layout attributes of `layout_width` and/or `layout_height` set to `match_parent`, then they will occupy the whole screen when you inflate them. Either set them to `wrap_content` or some fixed value to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a ActivityGroup within the Tab where you want to change the Activity. If you just go on and create a new Activity and display it, your Tab Layout is no longer visible. 
See this: http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity

Comment: I'm not creating a new activity not even changing an activity. I'm just trying to inflate a new view.