# Android: View returning null when called?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a view being created based on a boolean option, the view is titled socialoptions which is defined in a separate xml file. The view returns null anytime I am trying to use it through methods such as `socialoptions.setClickable(true);`.

Java Code:

```
        if (isUserProfile) {
            Log.d("user","user");
            middlelayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.layout.usermiddlelayout);
        } else {
            Log.d("item","item");
            middlelayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById (R.layout.itemmiddlelayout);
            socialoptions = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.socialoptions);
            map = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.map);
        }
```

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemmiddlelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sociallayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/socialoptions"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/maplayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is `middlelayout` also `null`?

Comment: Yes, middlelayout is also null.

Comment: I suspect, then, that you are not referencing this from the root view, or from the `Activity` in which `setContentView` is called. Try calling `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` and see if that is `null`.

Comment: The content view is set to a separate xml then the one holding the middlelayout, I was hoping to call it despite not being there. In the same way you can reference drawables across various files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As per comments*:

You cannot do what you're trying to do; you cannot reference an XML layout which has not been set up. That is to say, you must use `setContentView` or [inflate such a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-an-layout) first.

A drawable is stored in the application as a referenceable object; it exists as a "file" within your APK. A layout is just data that means nothing until it is "created".

Once you set the content view or inflate your layout into view, you will not receive `null` objects anymore when referencing the layout's contents.

Answer (score 0):

If the xml page is saved as usermiddlelayout.xml, you can use R.layout.usermiddlelayout. If the linear layout inside the xml file set it's id to android:id="@+id/itemmiddlelayout" you should use R.id.itemmiddlelayout and not R.layout.itemmiddlelayout.

Here,

middlelayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById (R.id.itemmiddlelayout);

Comment: This solved a separate problem by not making the middlelayout return null but the socialoptions still does. Thanks for helping.