# How to replace the exising layout of @include programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

In my xml file I have include layout using @inlcude and wants to replace that layout using id programmatically.For example in my layout I have the following xml files

```
<include android:id="@+id/promo1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/one_promo">
</include>
```

in java code I want like below code to replace the existing layout with new.

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.promo1);
v.setView(R.layout.new_promo);
```

Is there any facility to change like this after including with @include within xml file.

Comment: Identify the Root ViweGroup in your activity and use remove method.

Comment: I know the concept of removing and adding views to parent.Need like the above scenario.

Comment: At the end how do you implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see at the [inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method. And there are lots of similar questions at stackoverflow, eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-an-layout).