# How to set CheckBox or Radio button at same place in layout screen?

Tags: android, json, layout

Fisrt i have a json data

```
[{"Test_ID":"6","Question_Text":"What is the length of the train?","Answer_Set_id":"1","Correct_Answer":"4","Correct_Answer_Text":null,Answer_choice_1":"45 km\/hr","Answer_choice_2":"50 km\/hr","Answer_choice_3":"54 km\/hr","Answer_choice_4":"55 km\/hr","Answer_Type":"checkbox"},

{"Test_ID":"6","Question_Text":" The speed of the train is:","Answer_Set_id":"2","Correct_Answer":"2","Answer_choice_1":"45 km\/hr","Answer_choice_2":"50 km\/hr","Answer_choice_3":"54 km\/hr","Answer_choice_4":"55 km\/hr","Answer_Type":"radio"},}
```

parse the json of answer type the show the checkbox or radio button at the same place.
 If Checkbox get the show the 4 checkbox in layout if radio get then show the 4 radio button at same place means replace the checkbox at radio button and vice versa.
How to do please help me guys??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inflate view

[How to inflate one view with a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-an-layout)

or set views `android:visibility="gone"` or `android:visibility="visible"`