# ViewGroup.addView does not display anything on the screen

Tags: android, viewgroup

I am developing for Android and I ran into a problem. When I use `addView` method of `ViewGroup` to add a `ViewGroup` object, it does not display anything on the screen.

Can anyone help me?

```
RelativeLayout fullLayout=new RelativeLayout(this); 
RelativeLayout top=new RelativeLayout(this); 
TextView phoneNumber=new TextView(context); 
phoneNumber.setText("137928833"); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams phoneParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
phoneParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); phoneParams.leftMargin=130; phoneParams.topMargin=120; 
top.addView(phoneNumber,phoneParams); 
fullLayout.addView(top,0);
```

I use setContentView(fullLayouot),it does not work.

Comment: please show some code. What are you trying to do and where did you got stuck?

Comment: RelativeLayout fullLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout top=new RelativeLayout(this);   TextView phoneNumber=new TextView(context);
    phoneNumber.setText("137928833");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams phoneParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    phoneParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    phoneParams.leftMargin=130;
    phoneParams.topMargin=120;
    top.addView(phoneNumber,phoneParams);
    fullLayout.addView(top,0); I use setContentView(fullLayouot),it does not work.

Comment: @xiaoxiaoniao: why dont you keep the above code (comment) in your question itself , so that every one can understand your problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

It simply doesn't work because you didn't set any layout parameters on your top level layout (fullLayout). no width no height and nothing....

on the other hand, you have instantiated relative layout params with ViewGroup values which normally should through exception.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to do; but instead of programmatically creating these views you could create an xml holding them and inflate that layout. Here are some other questions that were asked that might be useful:

- [How to inflate one view into a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-an-layout)
- [How to switch views in activity](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_switch_views_in_an_activity-t10063.html)

Comment: Thanking for you answer,but I want to create these views dynamically instead of using xml.@Ryan Smith