# Add multiple custom views to layout programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

If I for example have empty layout like this:

#### layout1.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 
</LinearLayout>
```

And some other Layout like this:

#### layout2.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 1" />
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
 
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to add `layout2.xml` to `layout1.xml` programmatically. I would need to have multiple different version `layout2.xml` which I would add when I want. Each one would have different text on `TextView` and `Button`s.

In case of regular Android `View` I would usually do it similarly like this with `addView`:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("HELLO");
    my_linear_layout.addView(tv1);

    Button btn2 = new Button(this);
    bt2.setText("WORLD");
    my_linear_layout.addView(btn2);
}
```

How can I do it if I don't have something simple like `TextView` or `Button`, and if I have my own XML defined `View`?

Would it be possible to somehow put all the views inside adapter like for a `ListView` and then get it when needed and just call `addView` on those `View`s?

Comment: Use LayoutInflator to do this
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-an-layout

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can inflate the `layout2.xml` file, edit the texts, and add it to the first layout:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewGroup mLinearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
        mLinearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        addLayout("This is text 1", "This is first button", "This is second Button");
    }

    private void addLayout(String textViewText, String buttonText1, String buttonText2) {
        View layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout2, mLinearLayout, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) layout2.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button1 = (Button) layout2.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button2 = (Button) layout2.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        textView1.setText(textViewText);
        button1.setText(buttonText1);
        button2.setText(buttonText2);

        mLinearLayout.addView(layout2);
    }
}
```

You may want to change `android:layout_height` of the `layout2.xml` root view to `wrap_content`.

If you are using ViewBinding, here is how it would look like for the `addLayout` function :

```java
MyLayoutBinding binding = MyLayoutBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), mLinearLayout, false);
binding.getTextView1().setText(textViewText);
binding.getButton1().setText(buttonText1);
binding.getButton2().setText(buttonText2);

mLinearLayout.addView(binding.getRoot());
```

Comment: How can I do this with view binding?

Comment: @Patrick check the edited answer

Comment: Please see below my answer.

Answer (score 17):

`layout1.xml` contains `ScrollView` as parent layout and main `LinearLayout` as child if no row item more screen size `ScrollView` handle overflow item with scroll:

**layout1.xml**

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Use [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to add row item to parent `LinearLayout`:

```java
private LinearLayout my_linear_layout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
    my_linear_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
        TextView button1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        TextView button3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setText("HELLO " + i);
        button2.setText("HELLO " + i);
        button3.setText("HELLO " + i);
        my_linear_layout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to access all button outside the view ?

Comment: Try to get child from my_linear_layout or add all buttons reference one array list.

Comment: Specified child already has a parent please call removeView()

Answer (score 5):

Try this method

Add `id` to `LinearLayout` 'layout1.xml':

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/firstlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

In `onCreate`:

```java
LinearLayout firstlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.firstlayout);

LinearLayout secondlayoout = (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout2, null); // inflating view from xml
TextView btn1 = (TextView) secondlayoout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setText("TEST");

firstlayout.addView(secondlayoout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this for view binding by using below.

```
val layoutBindingView: LayoutBinding =
            LayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
layoutBindingView.textView.text = "TextOne"

val layoutBindingView: LayoutBinding =
            LayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
layoutBindingView.textView.text = "Text Two"
```