# Is it possible to add Views in code?

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, textview, seekbar

We are creating this Bar machine where the machine is hooked up to a server. 
From a client (in our case an Android application), you can mix your drink.

Problem is that we started out with 4 different liquids. But if we want the project to be more dynamic, we want to be able to have more or less than 4 liquids in the machine.

In our app we have for each liquid a Seekbar and textviews for displaying fluid name and volume while dragging the Seekbar.

The app client receives fluid information from the server.

If we wish to have let's say 5 fluids, can I somehow add more seekbars and textviews from the code? I'm having difficulty seeing that, because with 4 liquids all Views are made in the xml-file with RelativeLayouts.

Have searched for it but have only seen ListViews but my UI is more complicated than plain textviews.

Comment: yes, it is possible ... use google to find similar questions here before asking

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128425/add-multiple-custom-views-to-layout-programmatically

Comment: Would you mind specify what I should look for when using google?

Comment: Probably, that is what you are searching for...

[How to Programmatically Add Views to Views][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views

Answer (score 0):

ListView use an ListAdapter that you have to implement, the ListAdapter can be used for anything (not only TextView).

[Android ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

If you want to add a view to a [ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ...)](http://[1]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)), you can also use :