# Is there anyway to Create a card on a click of a button for Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Is there any way to Create a card on a click of a button Android?

[normal state of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iCwj.png)

then when I click the add button it will generate another card similar to the first one

[after clicking the add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrSne.png)

Comment: have your tried any code?

Comment: I like @ronginat 's answer. But if you're not using a recyclerview, you can add a new view to your layout. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012381/duplicate-a-view-programmatically-from-an-already-existing-view

Comment: Please do not tag with `Android-studio` just because you use it. This tag is for question about the IDE itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use A `RecyclerView` with `RecyclerView.Adapter` and some sort of `List` of elements.
 When you want to create a new card, simply add an element to the end of your list and call `notifyItemInserted(position)`.
[Some reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845069/add-a-new-item-to-recyclerview-programmatically)

Also, you can use a vertical `LinearLayout` to hold your views and Create a xml file to represent your cards. Every time you want to add a new view, inflate the xml file and type `layout.addView(view)`
It will be more complicate to manage your cards, but if you plan only to add new cards it may be simpler than a recyclerview.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27128720/10470378) 
These are the best ways i know to achieve what you asked.

Comment: ronginat
i just assume that i'll be needing the  recyclerview there
are there other options that will not be needing the recyclerview?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you ronginat now 
i know where sould i start 
thanks a lot