# Add fragment to underlying SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview, setcontentview

How do I add a fragment to an underlying SurfaceView? I get the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0050
```

I think this is due to not setting any layout in the setContentView such as

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

instead I set a reference to a custom surfaceview ...

```
final GameSurface gs = new GameSurface(this);
setContentView(gs);
```

Then in the surfaceview callback ontouch(...) - a fragment is supposed to load if the user clicks on the surface

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

 .....

        FragmentManager fragmentManager =((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ExchangeFragment fragment = new ExchangeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.relLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

thanks in advance

Edit:

No crash any longer but the fragment wont show up. why?
Thanks to @Kelevandos and the answer at another stack-thread

[How to inflate one view with a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-a-layout)

That is, I hade to add AttributSet to the custom surfaceViews constructor.

What is missing? Here is the xml-file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


   <se.brickgame.brickbreaker.GameSurface

        android:id="@+id/surfaceId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

   <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
   </RelativeLayout>
```

edit 2:

I also added this to the code

```
 fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
 System.out.println("FRAGMENT ISADDED = " + fragment.isAdded());
 System.out.println("FRAGMENT VISIBLE = " + fragment.isVisible());
 System.out.println("FRAGMENT HIDDEN = " + fragment.isHidden());
 System.out.println("FRAGMENT ISINLAYOUT = " + fragment.isInLayout());
```

and got the following output

```
11-25 16:09:07.957 12155-12155/se.brickgame.brickbreaker ISystem.out: FRAGMENT ISADDED = true
11-25 16:09:07.957 12155-12155/se.brickgame.brickbreaker I/System.out: FRAGMENT  VISIBLE = true
11-25 16:09:07.957 12155-12155/se.brickgame.brickbreaker I/System.out: FRAGMENT HIDDEN = false
11-25 16:09:07.957 12155-12155/se.brickgame.brickbreaker I/System.out: FRAGMENT ISINLAYOUT = false
```

So .. it seems to be there but not in the layout - how to interpret that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `GameSurface` does not have a view inside it with id `R.id.relLayout`. Fragment transaction must be given a container into which you want to put the fragment.

One solution would be to create a layout for the `Activity`, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <GameSurface/>
    <RelativeLayout/> //This is the Fragment container
</RelativeLayout>
```

set it as the content layout of your `Activity` and retrieve your `GameSurface` like this:

```
final GameSurface gs = (GameSurface) findViewById(R.id.yourSurfaceId);
```

This is actually the way layouts and Views should be handled in Android, so it will be best if you redesigned your solution like this.

If for some reason you can't/don't want to, you will have to reconsider replacing the `Fragment` part with another approach, which will not require a `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks but the fragment wont show up. I cannot figure it out right now, see edit.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot