# How to make a new layout with custome values xml (java)?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make a new layout customizing **the image** of it, `R.id.imageStep1`. I am getting an error at `layout.addView(guideLayout)`.

This is my java class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.guide_base);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.guide_base);
    ViewGroup guideLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.guide_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    ImageView image;
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guideImage1);

    String guideImage = intent.getStringExtra("guideImage");
    int resId = guideLayout.getResources().getIdentifier(guideImage, "drawable", null);
    image.setImageResource(resId);

    layout.addView(guideLayout);

    String guideTitle = intent.getStringExtra("guideTitle");
    String guideText = intent.getStringExtra("guideText");
}
```

Why is `guideLayout` null if I initiated in:

`guideLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.guide_layout);`

**Is this the correct method to add a new xml file with values customized?**

guide_base.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/guide_base">

</LinearLayout>
```

guide_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/guide_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/one_black_36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageStep1"
        android:contentDescription="Steps to follow"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleStep1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreenPrimary"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageStep1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageStep1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageStep1"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGuide1"
        android:contentDescription="Guide Step 1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titleStep1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titleStep1"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleStep1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreenSecondary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:text="Si una persona está despierta pero menos alerta de lo usual, hágale una serie de preguntas sencillas, como:  ¿Cuál es su nombre? ¿Qué día es? ¿Cuántos años tiene?" />

    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/persona_desmayada"
        android:id="@+id/guideImage1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="zzz"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textGuide1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alertavecino.alertavecino/com.alertavecino.alertavecino.guide}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference**

Comment: Can you please add you XML file?
use :
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_Main);
instead of
    image = (ImageView) guideLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageview_Main);

Comment: You don't have R.id.guide_base in your XML.
I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

You are using 
    setContentView(R.layout.guide_base);
Which I guess doesn't have guide_layout in it.
In that case, it will not find it and will return null.

Please explain what you are trying to do and I will try to suggest an answer.

Comment: I do have an guide_base.xml, let me post it so you can see it.

Comment: You need to inflate the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In setContentView(R.layout.guide_base); you are declaring the Layout of the activity. In your layout you have only guide_base which in that case

```
    ViewGroup guideLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.guide_layout);
```

will return null, as it doesn't exists in the guide_base layout.
Why don't you include the guide_layout layout inside the guide_base?

In case you want to reuse it in other placse. you can edit your guide_base to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/guide_base">
        <include layout="@layout/guide_layout"
          android:id="@+id/guide_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

as described in: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Or to use inflator to create the guide_layout view. see [How to inflate one view with a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-a-layout)

Comment: You can use @Malik Kawee answer in case you choose to inflate the view.

Comment: This lets me inflate it with a new layout but how can I change the attribute of the XML new layout?

Comment: After you inflate it, 
use 
    ImageView image;
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guideImage1);

    String guideImage = intent.getStringExtra("guideImage");
    int resId = guideLayout.getResources().getIdentifier(guideImage, "drawable", null);
    image.setImageResource(resId);
That should work.
If you are inflating the view, 
 Use 
    image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.guideImage1);
instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LayoutInflater to call other view.

```
private View view = null ;
Button addbutton = null;
ViewGroup parent = null;
LayoutInflater inflater = null;
inflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
addbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainxml);


addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, null);
    parent.addView(view);
 }
});
```

Try this. Hope this helps :)