# How to use the same basic layout with different contents in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 3 different pages that all have their own fragment XML file. These fragments are basically the same for all 3 pages, they only differ in the content: Page 1 displays a RadioGroup, Page 2 shows a checkbox and Page 3 simply shows text.

On every page, there is a title and a description on the top and a button on the bottom. The content is displayed between the description and the button.

Currently  I have copied the fragment file and just changed the content part. But this solution does not seem to be the best because I have to change 3 files when there is a layout change.

What is the recommended way to do this? Extend the LinearLayout class? Put all elements in one file and dynamically show/hide the elements I need?  Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is you could have the page XML file and in the area your content differs, you could put an empty layout tag with an ID like `layoutPlaceholder` in that space, which is where you would programmatically insert the RadioGroup, the Checkbox, and Text XML layouts in your code.

The XML structure could look like this:

```
- Page.xml
   - Page_RadioGroup.xml
   - Page_checkbox.xml
   - Page_text.xml
```

[This question explains how to inflate those sub-page xml files inside Page.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-a-layout)

If you wanted to create the RadioGroup, Checkbox, and Text content programmatically instead of having 3 extra xml files, you could do that too, but I personally like to keep all my element layout in XML.

Comment: I will try this, thank you!
Do you know if there is a possibility to do this all in XML? What I would need is something like a reverse-include. This means I want to specify a file (Page.xml) with the basic layout and a placeholder in  it. In every Page_*.xml I would include Page.xml and just overwrite the placeholder to this file. Just like you overwrite abstract classes. The content would be abstract while the basic layout is already implemented and does not have to be overwritten.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I think this kind of problem is too complicated for the scope of what the XML layouts can do. I think the only options are (a) put all the views in the one XML file and make them all invisible and reveal/hide as needed (b) have a placeholder layout tag in page.xml to insert views into (c) have three separate XML files.

Comment: Thanks :) I think I'll use solution b